# Medical Images and workflow

Tags: medical-imaging, x-rays, ct-scans, healthcare-data, bone-scan

What is the general workflow involved in managing images such as X-ray, scan etc in a day to day job of a healthcare-technician or a doctor?

I am interested to know more about how these images are shared, viewed, tagged and passed around for review.

Any online resources regarding this will be useful, as I am really struggling to get resources around this coming from a tech back ground.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picture_archiving_and_communication_system

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the IHE Radiology Scheduled Workflow integration profile in [IHE Radiology (RAD) Technical Framework](http://ihe.net/uploadedFiles/Documents/Radiology/IHE_RAD_TF_Vol1.pdf). This explains a common workflow model.

Comment: Welcome to Health, Dave! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link just for reference.